# Telerik mvc grid custom command popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have got a grid and a custom command button inside the grid.
My goal is to open a Telerik popup window and pass the column values to this popup window.

So far I created a grid with the custom command which opens a Telerik window. But I am not sure how to pass the values from the grid to the popup window.

**The Grid**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Lagerbase.Models.Artikel>()
    .Name("CompanyGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        ....
        columns.Bound(o => o.Id);
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Buchen").Click("Buchen"));
    }
    ...
 )
```

**The popup window**

```
(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("window")
    .Title("About Alvar Aalto")
    .Content(@<text>
        <h4>Id: (this is where I want to display the Id from the grid)</h4>
    </text>)
    .Resizable()
    .Width(600)
    .Visible(false)
    .Actions(actions => actions.Pin().Minimize().Maximize().Close())
)
```

**The JavaScript function**

```
<script>
    function Buchen(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#window").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
    }
</script>
```

In the popup window I marked the area where I want to pass the column value, based on which button was pressed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get current data item in javascript and then get the id property from it.

```
 var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
$("#lblMyValue").text(dataItem.Id);
```